# Cakephp how to create a nested foreach

Tags: foreach, nested, associations, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3. I have to create a view for a Group in which in every Subject, there will be Lessons but in my case:

Group hasMany subjects
Subject hasMany lessons

Here is my code in the GroupsController:

```
public function mygroup()
    {

        $this->loadModel('Lessons');

        $group = $this->Groups->get($this->Auth->user('group_id'), [
            'contain' => ['Subjects', 'Users']
        ]);

        $lesson = $this->Lessons->find('all');
        $this->set('lesson', $lesson);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['lesson']);
        $this->set('group', $group);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['group']);

    }
```

I have to load lessons model because it is not associated with group, in mygroup.ctp view:

```
<?php if (!empty($group->subjects)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($group->subjects as $subjects): ?>

    <?= h($subjects->subject) ?>
    <?= h($subjects->id) ?>
            <?= h($subjects->created) ?>

    <?php foreach ($lesson as $lesson): ?>
    <?php if ($subjects->id == $lesson->subject_id): ?>

    <?= h($lesson->lesson) ?>
    <?= h($lesson->subject_id) ?>
            <?= h($lesson->created) ?></div>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to view lesson just below of its subject where it belongs. I don't know but the for each loop for the subject is working but the for each loop of lessons it only work for the first subject it displays: 
Something like this:

> Subject1
>        Lesson1 for sub1
>        Lesson2 for sub1
>        Lesson3 for sub1
>
> Subject2
>
> Subject3
>
> Subject4
>
> Subject5

The lessons are not showing in the subject 2 to 5 yet there should be.
Can u help me with this? Or is there any other way to do it? If there someone. Very much appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: you can contain deeper associations like 'contain' => ['Subjects', 'Users', 'Subjects.Lessons']

Comment: My code runs properly now. Thank you for the suggestion :)